# symfony4 test.html.php template does not exist

Tags: php, symfony4

After enabling the php engine by editing the config/packages/framework.yaml, I am now facing the "The template ::/test/test.html.php" does not exit" error !!

Controller :

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class TestController extends Controller
    {
    /**
    * @Route("/test.html.php", name="testphp")
    */
    public function testphp(){
        return $this->render('test/test.html.php');
    }
}
```

Path: **Templates/test/test.html.php**

Comment: Can we see your file tree?

Comment: And are you sure it's not test/test.html.twig

Comment: As a side note: your route does not have to have the extension (or even the same name for that matter!). You can simply have `* @Route("/test", name="testphp")`

Comment: Thanks for your comment guys !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. The Symfony team has not yet updated the php templating engine, so it looks for files not in the `templates` folder, but in `src/Resources/views/`. If you were to put your file in `src\Resources\views\test\test.html.php` everything works (I tested it).

Comment: You're welcome. I would also look into using Twig because it seems like the whole php templating is something that is no longer desired in Symfony 4. See the related github issue I created: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/27964

Comment: Thanks for your cool advice but after making the changes that resovled the first problem, I adjusted the path for the require_once to fit the new Resources/view location of the requiring file and now I am having another critical problem,
` The autoloader expected class "App\Resources\views\test\config" to be defined in file "/home/user1645/projects/application_symfony/vendor/composer/../../src/R  
  esources/views/test/test.config". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.  `

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with "I adjusted the path for the require_once". I think it is best to just create a new question with your code so I (and others) can have a look what might be the issue.

Comment: I somehow solved the problem yesterday , again, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

run composer require symfony/twig-bundle you will get a template folder with base.html.twig file